# Java servlet getParameter in post-request truncated

Tags: java, servlets, request

we have a servlet and sending a post-message to it. In the networktraffic, we could see that the parameter is complete. When calling the request.getParameter(paramname) function in the java servlet we get the value truncated after a special number of characters, not a specific character. So when adding some characters to "somewordthatislong" the position where the param is truncated inside the date moves to the left.

Does anyone have an idea why this happens?

**Parameter post message from network**

```
q=somewordthatislong+AND+document_meta_documentarchive_publicationsdatum_manipulated%3A%5B2014%2F01%2F01+TO+2015%2F12%2F31%5D
```

**Calling the request.getParameter(paramname) function**

```
q=somewordthatislong
    +AND+document_meta_documentarchive_publicationsdatum_manipulated%3A%5B2014%2F01%2F01+TO+2
```

**Url-decoded value of the param is**

```
q=somewordthatislong AND document_meta_documentarchive_publicationsdatum_manipulated:[2014/01/01 TO 2015/12/31]
```

Comment: Where have you captured the parameter from network: on client or server side?

Comment: This is what the browser network tab shows.

Comment: how "long" do you mean? In tomcat there's a "maxPostSize" configuration (in the Connector) but usually it's very large. I'd check whether someone tweaked this configuration on your size. Or whether your post is huge due to some other fields.

Comment: This is what I expected. Run wireshark on Server's machine and try to capture the network. I guess that you will see truncated version there.

Answer (score 0):

Further analysis has shown that there is a class extending HTTPRequest and getParameter, which cuts q after ~100 chars. Sorry Guys was not obvious for me to see because of dependency injection.

Thought it was a standard HTTPRequest. Thanks for your help!